# How can I filter out GPS errors in GPS data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gps, move

Although I've filtered out most of the outliers/GPS errors, there are still some that remains. A plot of the data is presented along with the code. As you can see in the first image, at around Lat 37, there are random lines shooting out of the graph. I'm not sure how I can further delete these GPS errors without going through each data point(there are over 60,000) and remove them. I've taken the liberty to provide a second image of a scatterplot with the altitude. Thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- TUVU.Lead_0412_2022
glimpse(df)
#View missing values from GPS error
is.na((df$location.long))

#Omit rows with missing geographical coordinates 
new_df <- na.omit(df)
view(new_df)
write.csv(new_df, "Modified_TUVU_data.csv")

#Create a boxplot to view outliers
boxplot(new_df$argos.altitude)


install.packages("ggstatsplot")
library(ggstatsplot)
data("new_df")

#Identify and visualize argos.altitude outliers in df
boxplot(New_Modified_TUVU_data$argos.altitude)$out

#Find outlliers using statistical methods
Q <- quantile(new_df$argos.altitude, probs = c(.25, .75), na.rm = FALSE)
iqr <- IQR(new_df$argos.altitude)
up <-  Q[2]+1.5*iqr # Upper Range  
low<- Q[2]-1.5*iqr # Lower Range???

#Elimate OUtliers using subset function 
eliminated<- subset(new_df, new_df$argos.altitude > (Q[2] - 1.5*iqr) & warpbreaks$breaks < (Q[2]+1.5*iqr))

#Visualize any remaining outliers
boxplot(eliminated)$out
#Subset until outliers no longer remain
new_new_df <- subset(eliminated, argos.altitude<3157)
#Final view of boxplot without outliers
boxplot(new_new_df$argos.altitude)$out
write.csv(new_new_df, "New_Modified_TUVU_data.csv")

attach(New_Modified_TUVU_data)

install.packages("scatterplot3d")
library(scatterplot3d)
attach(New_Modified_TUVU_data)
scatterplot3d(location.long, location.lat, argos.altitude,
              highlight.3d = TRUE, angle = -100,
              type = "h", main = "3D Scatterplot Example"
)

library(dplyr)
arrange(New_Modified_TUVU_data, argos.altitude)
arrange(New_Modified_TUVU_data, argos.altitude)
arrange(New_Modified_TUVU_data, desc(argos.altitude))

persp(New_Modified_TUVU_data$location.lat, New_Modified_TUVU_data$location.long, New_Modified_TUVU_data$argos.altitude)
install.packages("plotly")
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(New_Modified_TUVU_data, aes(location.lat, location.long)) + 
  geom_path()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Random thoughts: 1) filter by horizontal accuracy if you have that. 2) if this is a track, calculate a rolling average of the distance between the last 3 points and detect outliers that are above some threshold.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to define which GPS point is an outlier and then you should think how to eliminate such point. For example, let suppose that point that is more than 10 meters far from nearest other point is an outlier. Therefore, you can use DBSCAN algorithm to identify such points. Here is a small example:

```
library(ggplot2)

df_lonlat <- data.frame(latitude = c(57.034491, 57.034084, 57.034043,
                                     57.034014, 57.034230, 57.034177,
                                     57.034124, 57.034224, 57.034234,
                                     57.034432),
                        longitude = c(24.151452, 24.152116, 24.152202,
                                      24.152352, 24.153221, 24.153296,
                                      24.153350, 24.153460, 24.153370,
                                      24.153380))

# Transform data to spatial format
sf_lonlat <- sf::st_as_sf(x = df_lonlat,
                          coords = c("longitude", "latitude"),
                          crs = 4326) # https://epsg.io/4326


# switch coordinates to Cartesian coordinate system (i.e., x,y format)
  # for other countries target coordinate reference system (crs) will be different
  # this transformation is used because you can't use DBSCAN for Long/Lat numbers
sf_lonlat <- sf::st_transform(x = sf_lonlat,
                              crs = 3059) # https://epsg.io/3059


# Calculate DBSCAN clusters (and find outliers)                 
dbscan_result <- dbscan::dbscan(x = sf::st_coordinates(sf_lonlat),
               eps = 10, # 10 meter distance. Points with larger distance will be classified in different cluster or will be classified as outlier
               minPts = 2) # here used 2 points, because df_lonlat has only 10 rows - small sample.

# Add DBSCAN clusters to df_lonlat and plot results
df_lonlat$cluster <- dbscan_result$cluster
# "0 cluster" are outliers, all other cluster numbers can be ignored


ggplot(df_lonlat, mapping = aes(x = latitude, y = longitude,
                                color = as.factor(cluster))) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = 'Latitude',
       y = 'Longitude',
       title = 'Long/Lat coordinates and outliers',
       color = 'Cluster') +
  theme_light()
```

I don't have original data (there will be lots of adjustment from your side), but I hope you understand the logic behind this code.
The code above was built with R version 4.1.0 and following R package versions: `sf (1.0.5), dbscan (1.1.8), ggplot2 (3.3.5)`.